# What is a simple and cross platform strategy to share memory between a C process and a Haskell program without FFI?

Tags: c, haskell, shared

I have a C program that renders images to a flat array of ints. I want to render that information to the screen using Haskell. What is a simple and cross platform way to read the memory on the C program from a Haskell program?

```
// C program allocs memory
int main(){
    int* data = malloc(10*sizeof(int));
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<10; ++i)
        data[i] = i;
    ...
}

-- Haskell program reads that memory
main = do
    cData <- readDataFromCProgram
    print cData
```

Since `data` is huge (in order of gigabytes), that has to be fast - that is, no writing to files and no streaming all the data again for each request. I.e., sharing the memory is needed. I can't use FFI for this.

Comment: posix shared memory? https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.3/docs/html/libraries/unix-2.7.0.1/System-Posix-SharedMem.html

Comment: Perhaps [memory](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/memory-0.3) and/or [primitive](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/primitive-0.6) could help.

Comment: I'd be curious as to *why* you can't use FFI for this. Raw access to memory isn't common in the Haskell ecosystem, and for good reason.

Comment: Now I don't remember exactly the reason, but I guess it was a bug on the FFI library of Haskell or something on those lines which basically meant I'd have to update the library myself (which I had no idea how to). I'm not sure...